# Can users without a financial services cloud license view/modify financial service cloud records in the same org?

Tags: sharing, licenses, record, data-model, financial-services-cloud

I'm working with a org that wants to leverage FSC for a subset of users, but wants visibility of those records by non-FSC users.

I have reviewed the FAQ guide and the developer documentation, but there is no clear answer as to what is visible/editable by users in the same org as it relates to the FSC data model.

I am opening a case with our account team as well, but want to post the question publicly for others who have the same question.

https://www.salesforce.com/ap/editions-pricing/financial-services-cloud/
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.212.0.financial_services_cloud_admin_guide.meta/financial_services_cloud_admin_guide/fsc_admin_gaps_limitations.htm

Answer (score 0):

Confirmed with Saleforce that users must have a FSC (financial services cloud) feature license to create, read, update, or delete any object or component that comes with the FSC package.